# Is it possible to using VLCMediaPlayer or AVMediaPlayer with TVMLJS on tvOS?

Tags: objective-c, vlc, tvos, tvml

Can I use other player (maybe override existing?) in TVJS ?
I following this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/114886/beginning-tvos-development-with-tvml-tutorial
and I want to play other media stream(rtmp etc..). 
Normally I can use VLCKit, but can I use it with app based on TVML?

Thanks for help;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely possible, as you can bridge between JavaScript and native code.

There is a WWDC session video about that: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-615/

Basically, it should be mainly a matter of passing the URLs you want to play from your JS to VLCKit's ObjC bindings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help! I can't voted up for your answer because of my reputation. I did it adding new viewController with my external player (registered it in JSContext) and running it via JavaScript in TVML ;)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same because the native TVML player does support my URL formats, I want to use VLC instead. Could you please explain how you did it in your case.